# Is the arrow anti pattern a standard in Scala

Tags: scala, coding-style, nested, standards, anti-patterns

The question first: Is the arrow anti pattern the way to do things in Scala?

I've been transitioning from Java to Scala for about 3 months now. I'm starting to see that the anti arrow pattern as a bit of a standard in Scala.

For example, in Java, I like to return from methods as soon as possible. We don't like a lot of inner nestings. If you have lots of them it's called the arrow anti pattern. You can read about it here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern

Java example:

```
boolean isValid(String input){
  if (input.trim().length() <1) return false //return early
  if (input.substring(0,3).equals("sth")) return false;

  //do some more checks for validity then return true

  return true
}
```

If I wrote this in Scala I'd have to use match-case statements which results in a lot of indenting. Keep in mind that this is just a dummy example where I try to convey only the nesting and indentation of Scala.

```
def isValid(input:String):  Boolean = {
  (input.trim.length < 1) match {
    case true => 
      input.substring(0,3) match {
        case sthCase if(sthCase=="sth") =>
          //do some more checks etc

          //eventually arrive at the "true" branch
               ... case valid => true

        case sthElse if (sthCase=="bla") => //some more code etc
        case _ => false
      }
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

I know this example could have been written the same way I wrote the Java one, but if instead of returning true or false I wanted to assign that value to a variable ie:`val valid = (input.trim.length < 1) match ...` then this is the only way to do it since you can't reassign to val. I could use `var` instead of `val`, but then I'd be using Java instead of Scala.

**Question, re-iterated:**
So the question is, is the arrow anti pattern the way to do things in Scala or am I missing something? Is there a better way to do in Scala what I just wrote (keeping in mind that I want that match statement result to be assigned to a `val` variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you can always use decomposition in Scala as long as all parts of the code are single entry/single exit. This works because nested functions in Scala can access the local variables of the outer function. E.g.:

```
def isValid(input: String): Boolean = {
  def testLength = input.trim.length >= 1
  def testSomething = input.substring(0, 3) == "sth"

  return testLength && testSomething
}
```

You can thus break down any arrow-like structure into its subcomponents as much as you desire.

Note also that using match for testing booleans or comparing something for equality is overkill.

Comment: It's not a really new technique, either. See ["Program Development by Stepwise Refinement" by Niklaus Wirth](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362577). It's probably a major reason why all languages in the Pascal family of languages have nested procedures/functions.

Comment: indeed, but it's a start. I will probably make another post continuing this question, but a bit deeper/more advanced than a few boolean values nested. thanks again

Comment: The `return` keyword can and should be omitted

Comment: As a stylistic preference, I like to make the `return` explicit at the end of long functions. Not only does it make it easier to visually find the end of a function (assuming you have syntax highlighting), it also makes it clear that we are dealing with a function instead of a procedure without having to inspect the function signature. The semantics are the same either way, so neither way is objectively better.

Comment: If you omit the `return` it makes your source "grep-able" for `return`s which could be replaced with something else.

Answer (score 3):

Your java example can easily be translated to an `if/else` in scala without explicit return and without any additional levels of nesting.

```
def isValid(input: String) = {
  if (input.trim().length() <1) false
  else if (input.substring(0,3).equals("sth")) false
  else true
}
```

`if/else` like everything in scala is an expression and has a return value, so you might as well use it for an assignment:

```
val isValid =
  if (input.trim().length() <1) false
  else if (input.substring(0,3).equals("sth")) false
  else true
```

Or in this case you could also simply write

```
val isValid = (input.trim().length() >= 1) && (!input.substring(0,3).equals("sth"))
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. I should have used a non boolean example to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 3):

If there are too many `return`s in a function, functions are missing:

```
def isValid(s: String): Boolean = {
  def isLengthValid = s.trim().length() > 0
  def shouldNotContainsSomething = s.substring(0, 3) != "sth"

  isLengthValid && shouldNotContainsSomething
}
```

Comment: No need to use `equals` for string comparison in Scala. The `==` operator automatically uses the `equals` method.

Comment: It was copied from the Java example - I just appended the `== false` to preserve the condition. So it should really be `!=`. I've updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do the cargo cult [just because some rule says so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36707/298389). The good thing in Scala is that you can do the best from both worlds -- e.g. sometimes algoritm written in a mutable style is much more clear than the immutable one.

By the way, there is also `require` method, which is used commonly for fail on validation (but it goes up with an exception).